# Using rsync to backup MySQL

Tags: mysql, unix, rsync

I use the following rsync command to backup my MySQL data to a machine within the LAN network. It works as expected.

```
rsync -avz /mysql/ root:PassWord@192.168.50.180:: /root/testme/
```

I just want to make sure that this is the correct way to use rsync.

I will also like to know if the 5 minute crontab entry for this will work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. don't use the `root` user of the remote machine for this. In fact, never directly connect to the root user, that's a major security risk. In this case, simply create a new user with few privileges that may only write to the backup location
2. Don't use a password for this connection, but instead use [public-key authentication](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Public_Key_Authentication)
3. Make sure that MySQL is not running when you do this, or you can easily get a corrupt backup.
4. Use [`mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) to create a dump of your database while MySQL is running. You can then safely copy that dump.

Answer (score 6):

I find a better way of doing backups of MySQL is to use the replication facility.

set up you backup machine as a slave of your master. Each transaction is then  automatically mirrored.

You can also shut down the slave and perform a full backup to tape from it. When you restart the slave it synchronises with the master again.

Comment: This will only work if you have complete binlogs on the master. Sometimes its best to restore the slave from a slightly stale backup (taken with `mysqldump --master-data`), followed by a `slave start`, to ensure that the resulting database is complete.

Comment: Yes, duplicate your database writes to another machine. Then, when you accidentally delete an entire table or database, you can just go to your replicated MySQL server and... oh shit.

Answer (score 5):

I don't really know about your rsync command, but I am not sure this is the right/best way to make backup with MySQL ; you should probably take a look at this page of the manual : [6.1. Database Backups](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/backup.html)

DB backups are not necessarily as simple as one might think, considering problems suchs as locks, delayed write, and whatever optimizations MySQL can do with its data... Especially if your tables are not using the MyISAM engine.

About the "*5 minutes crontab*" : you are doing this backup every five minutes ? If your data is that sensible, you should probably think about something else, like replication to another server, to always have an up-to-date copy.